# kubernetes : What are valid node fields

Tags: kubernetes, nodes

I would like to use *podAffinity* with *matchFields*.
On the web I only found examples with field metadata.name :

```
- matchFields:
  - key: metadata.name
    operator: NotIn
    values:
    - worker-1
```

I would like to know if there are any other valid node fields I can use and how/where I can find them?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some digging and I found out that `Matchfields` was introduced because of the issue with scheduling `DaemonSets`. The Controller that creates pod was depending the `kubernetes.io/hostname` label on a Node. This whole setup was assuming that this label is being equal to the node name which turned out wrong one becuase node name and `hostname` are distinct in some cases. See [#61410](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/61410) for more reading.  This also explains why there example of using this is only related to DaemonSet in the docs.

Because of that  PR #[62002](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/62002) was merged which added `MatchFields` to `NodeSelectorTerm` with the release note that explains that only `metadata.name` is being supported:

```
Added `MatchFields` to `NodeSelectorTerm`; in 1.11, it only support `metadata.name`.
```

So at the time of this writing the only supported field is `metadata.name`. I've check also [tests code](https://github.com/k82cn/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/apis/core/validation/validation_test.go#L8050-L8075) and it appears that this behavior has not changed till now.

PS. Please note that this can only be used in `NodeSelector` and not applicable in `PodAffinity/PodAntiAffinity`

Comment: confirmed `metadata.name` is still the only the supported key in `matchFields` as of [k8s v1.23.5](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.23.5/pkg/apis/core/validation/validation_test.go#L8840-L8865) (thanks for the validation deep link!)